# What is Device product is 'grouper' in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to flash nexus 7's O.S. having 4.1.1 rom and trying to upgrate to 4.2.1. I am getting problem while flashing the android OS.How can i resolved the below problem?

**Device product is 'grouper'.
Update requires 'tilapia'.**

Your help will be appreciated...

Than you :)

Comment: http://androidforums.com/nexus-7-all-things-root/668162-grouper-vs-tilapia.html

Answer (score 2):

grouper is nexus 7 (wi-fi)
see here: https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers